# Find total number of characters in CLOB and XMLTYPE datatype column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, clob, xmltype

I have **Oracle 12c** version database.

I created table with **CLOB** and **XMLTYPE** datatype columns and Inserted some sample data.

I need to find total number of character in CLOB and XMLTYPE column.
Whatever the character-set used in those columns, just need a count.

Those two columns have huge data. So string operation ( i.e **length()** ) is not possible.

How to find the total number of character in those two columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `getlength` in `dbms_lob` package

```
select
   dbms_lob.getlength(t.clob_col)
  ,dbms_lob.getlength(t.XML_col.getClobVal())
from  table t
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=879b822fc1e74e11da58f9555fa51885)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried and found that the count is not accurate sometime. Ex fiddle                                                                                                                                                        https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5002a0f0ada7dfcf026bb9f604507a4b

Comment: xml contains whitspaces and carriage returns, these are also characters that are counted. have a look at a dump: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32a9c0d92bea3c4849b6f6a1f55508ff)*

Comment: But in this sample data, there is no extra space.

Comment: there is a carriage return that is automaticly added in XML

Comment: How to count carriage return too?. Need total count including character, empty space and carriage return